# How to override a constraint in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I have a scenario where i need to allocate leaves under special request type if the total available leaves is ZERO.I found that  there is a constraint defined which calculates the number of available leaves, and raises a warning using "check_holidays" function. How can i override this function, to build my logic..

I gave a sample try in custom ad-dons, but nothing positive..

Here is my Implementation:

```
class my_leave(osv.osv):
    _inherit:hr.holidays
    _check_holidays = lambda self, cr, uid, ids, context=None: self.check_holidays(cr, uid, ids)
    _constraints = [
      (_check_holidays, "You don't have sufficient leaves to apply. please contact your manager to allocate leaves")
    ]  
    def check_holidays(self, cr, uid, ids,methodname):
        raise Warning("OverRidden Method invoked") 
my_leave()
```

Comment: Any ideas on overriding in openerp?

Answer (score 0):

To redefine a python constraint, you can override it by setting the same method function name:

In a module puts:

```
class mrp_bom(orm.Model):

    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'



    def _check_product(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

        return True



    _constraints = [(_check_product, 'Override of _check_product constraint', ['product_id'])]
```

(copied)